# What filter is used to remove corner effect on result

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Below is output
[image]

Here are those marked in red circle. There are lots of such line the image, I have marked only 3 circle. How to remove these lines? Is there any filter to remove this line? I think, this is due to presence of corner.

Comment: Is this Stroke Width Transform?

Comment: yes... it is SWT (improved version implemented by me)

Comment: I implemented SWT that can be easily segmented which is not improved in existing SWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Median filter to remove that thing.

Try this code and see the difference while changing the value of the trackbar (mask size).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

#image window
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.namedWindow('image2')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('mask','image',1,10,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('mask2','image2',1,10,nothing)

#loading images
img = cv2.imread('VfgSN.png')     # load your image with path
gray_im = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

while True:
    # get current positions of trackbars
    m = cv2.getTrackbarPos('mask','image')
    m2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('mask2','image2')
    median = cv2.medianBlur(gray_im,(2*m+1))
    median2 = cv2.medianBlur(img,(2*m2+1))
    cv2.imshow('image',median)
    cv2.imshow('image2',median2)
    #press ESC to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resultant image with mask : 5

[image]

In grayscale (with the same mask)

[image]

But then it also affects the other parts of the image. If you don't want that to happen to the other part. You can apply this filter in your Region of Interest only.

Hope it helps.

Comment: median filter works for only color imaged.but what filter for gray scaled the image (as in my) is just a connected component output of Stroke Width transform so I need to apply for grayscale.

Comment: It gives me the same result in grayscale. See the updated answer. I'm sorry i'm new to opencv python. I didn't understand stroke width transform part. It might be possible that this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you say that it is not working for grayscale images. Median filter invariant to channel size, it can be 3 (colored), it can be 1 (grayscale) or it can be anything. Other than doing something wrong you don't have enough information about median filter. Please read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter